# как реализовать остаток от деления в обратную сторону?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, дискретная-математика

Предположим У меня сейчас такой код в цикле
C++

```
a = (a+3) % (13)
```

Я получаю такие результаты

> 3
>   6
>   9
>   12
>   2
>   5

Теперь я бы хотел сделать другой цикл в обратной последовательности. Где результат будет такой

> 5
>   2
>   12
>   9
>   6
>   3

Comment: Мало информации для ответа. Приведите кусок кода побольше, или уточните, что именно Вам надо? Переписать код или найти другую формулу, такую, которая формировала бы обратную последовательность?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Просто замени `3` на `10`:

```js
function *direct(a0) {
  var a = a0;

  do {
    yield a
    a = (a+3) % 13
  } while (a !== a0)
}

function *reverse(a0) {
  var a = a0;

  do {
    yield a
    a = (a+10) % 13
  } while (a !== a0)
}

console.log([...direct(3)].join(" "))
console.log([...reverse(5)].join(" "))
```